# Godot: attempt to call function 'get_texture' in base 'null instance' on a null instance

Tags: godot

I've got a texture painter prototype, but like the title says, I am getting the error message "attempt to call function 'get_texture' in base 'null instance' on a null instance" whenever I try to run the program. Script:

```
func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    var camera = get_parent().get_node("Camera")
    if camera != null:
        var from = camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
        var to = from + camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_position) * raycast_length
        var space_state = get_world().direct_space_state
        var result = space_state.intersect_ray(from, to)
        if result:
            var children = result.collider.get_children()
            for child in children:
                if child is MeshInstance:
                    if selected_mesh != null:
                        selected_mesh.material_override = null
                    selected_mesh = child
                    selected_mesh.material_override = SpatialMaterial.new()
                    selected_mesh.material_override.albedo_texture = selected_mesh.get_surface_material(result.shape).get_texture("albedo_texture")
                else:
                    if selected_mesh != null:
                        selected_mesh.material_override = null
                        selected_mesh = null
        else:
            if selected_mesh != null:
                selected_mesh.material_override = null
                selected_mesh = null
```

The error is happening on the line

```
selected_mesh.material_override.albedo_texture = selected_mesh.get_surface_material(result.shape).get_texture("albedo_texture")
```

To me, it does not look like the selected_mesh is being set to a null instance. Could someone explain what is causing this?

Comment: Is this your attempt at texture painting? I gave you references in a comment on that question.

Answer (score 0):

Review the facts:

- You are getting the error

  > attempt to call function 'get_texture' in base 'null instance' on a null instance

  which tells you that you are trying to call `get_texture` in an invalid instance.
- An you are getting in the line:

  ```
  selected_mesh.material_override.albedo_texture = selected_mesh.get_surface_material(result.shape).get_texture("albedo_texture")
  ```

---

Pop quiz! what is the thing that is an invalid instance?

Well, you are trying to call `get_texture` (which is what the error says) on this:

```
selected_mesh.get_surface_material(result.shape)
```

So that must be an invalid instance.

---

You might wonder if `selected_mesh` could be `null`. Well, if `selected_mesh` was null, then the error from Godot would say `get_surface_material`. Makes sense?

*Well, actually if `selected_mesh` was `null`, you would have gotten the error when trying to set `selected_mesh.material_override`.*

---

You seem to be making a wrong assumption. It is not a material per shape. I repeat: It is not a material per shape. Furthermore, these are the collision shapes, which are a physics concept. And the materials are associated with the *surfaces* of a mesh, which is a graphics concept.

You need to rethink your approach.